# 1 button to toggle 3 sort variations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 buttons in my view. Each of them have single work to do.

Now I want them to be a one key that is doing 3 things:

With each click toggling through each sort

```js
const buttonAsc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-asc")
const buttonDesc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-desc")
const buttonNo = document.getElementById("Sort-item-no")
const times = document.getElementsByClassName("time")
const originalHours = []
for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
  const hour = times[i].innerText;
  originalHours.push(hour)
}
buttonAsc.onclick = function() {
  let hours = []
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    const hour = times[i].innerText;
    hours.push(hour)
  }
  hours.sort()
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
  }
}
buttonDesc.onclick = function() {
  let hours = []
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    const hour = times[i].innerText;
    hours.push(hour)
  }
  hours.sort()
  hours.reverse()
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
  }
}
buttonNo.onclick = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < originalHours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = originalHours[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item-asc">Sort Asc</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item-desc">Sort Desc</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item-no">No Sort</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have a question (about a specific problem while making the change)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a super-array that has the three versions of the list (ascending, descending, unsorted). Then at every click extract the first list from that super-array, and at the same time add it again at the back of the list. Use this list for the display:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("Sort-item");
const times = [...document.getElementsByClassName("time")];
const originalHours = times.map(time => time.textContent);
// Pre-build the three versions of the list
const allHours = [[...originalHours].sort(), [...originalHours].sort().reverse(), originalHours];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Cycle the three lists: 
    const hours = allHours.shift();
    allHours.push(hours);
    for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        times[i].firstElementChild.textContent = hours[i];
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item">Sort Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need the `div` elements to be *relocated* (because you had specific attributes on them or references to them), then you could store them similarly in the arrays:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("Sort-item");
const container = document.querySelector(".item-sort");
const times = [...document.querySelectorAll(".time")];
const originalItems = times.map(time => [time.parentNode, time.textContent]);
const sortedItems = [...originalItems].sort((a,b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
                                      .map(a => a[0]); // Only keep node reference
// Pre-build the three versions of the list
const allItems = [sortedItems, [...sortedItems].reverse(), 
                  originalItems.map(a => a[0])];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Cycle the three lists: 
    const items = allItems.shift();
    allItems.push(items);
    for (const item of items) {
        container.appendChild(item);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item">Sort Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but i wanna sort the <div> with sorting hour , i mean when this is sorting by hours relocate each <div>

Comment: Relocating the `div` is less efficient. In the example you gave it would not make any difference. All `div` elements are the same except their content. So if the content is swapped then what is the difference?

Comment: Anyway, I added a snippet in my answer where the `div` elements are relocated. But you really should update your question with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered keeping only one button?
You could a global variable "count" that you increment each time the button is clicked. Then, with an "if" statement, you could fire each of the three functions, depending on the value of the counter?

Comment: That is a comment. For an answer that implemented your suggestion, see my earlier answer

Comment: @mplungjan users with less than 50 reputations can't comment

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to move the item div around

```js
const button = document.getElementById("sort");
const items  = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
const times  = document.querySelectorAll(".time");
const container = document.querySelector(".item-sort");
const originalHours = []
for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
  const hour = times[i].innerText;
  originalHours.push(hour);
  items[i].setAttribute("data-time",hour); // add the time to the item div
}
const sortClasses = ["nosort","asc","desc"];
let cnt = 0;
button.addEventListener("click",function() {
  let hours = originalHours.slice();
  this.className="";
  cnt++;
  if (cnt>=sortClasses.length) cnt=0;
  this.classList.toggle(sortClasses[cnt]);
  
  if (this.classList.contains("asc")) {
    hours.sort();
    this.innerText = "Descending";
  }  
  else if (this.classList.contains("desc")) {
    hours.sort().reverse();
    this.innerText = "Unsorted";
  }  
  else this.innerText = "Ascending";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    let sel = "[data-time='"+hours[i]+"']"; // selector based on time
    let itemDiv = document.querySelector(sel);
    if (itemDiv) container.appendChild(itemDiv);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="sort" class="nosort" title="Click to sort">Ascending</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/9ff?text=15:20" /></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/99f?text=13:10" /></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/ff9?text=18:40" /></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , but i wanna relocate <div> after sorting , i mean the <div> that have a small hour get first and ....

Comment: Updated the code to move the item around instead of inserting time. Your original question was not clear on this

Answer (score 0):

A more user friendly approach would be to use a dropdown instead of multiple clicks.

Allowing you to choose which sort method you want instead of having to determine what happened from the result.

```js
const sortOptions = document.getElementById('Sort-options');
const times = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
const originalHours = [];
for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    const hour = times[i].innerText;
    originalHours.push(hour)
  }

sortOptions.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  let selection = event.target.value;
  let hours = originalHours.slice();
  
  if (selection === 'Sort Asc') {
        hours.sort();
      }
  
  if (selection === 'Sort Desc') {
        hours.sort().reverse()
      }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
  }
});
```

```html
    <div class="full-item">  
  <select id="Sort-options">
    <option value="" selected>No Sort</option>
    <option value="Sort Asc">Sort Asc</option>
    <option value="Sort Desc">Sort Desc</option>
  </select>
  
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is harder to select something than to click a few times, but not a bad idea

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this and one of them is as follow

```js
const buttonAsc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-asc")
const buttonDesc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-desc")
const buttonNo = document.getElementById("Sort-item-no")
const times = document.getElementsByClassName("time")
const originalHours = []
for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
  const hour = times[i].innerText;
  originalHours.push(hour)
}
buttonAsc.onclick = function() {
  let hours = []
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    const hour = times[i].innerText;
    hours.push(hour)
  }
  hours.sort()
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
  }
  buttonAsc.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  buttonDesc.parentElement.classList.add("active");
}
buttonDesc.onclick = function() {
  let hours = []
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    const hour = times[i].innerText;
    hours.push(hour)
  }
  hours.sort()
  hours.reverse()
  for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
  }
  buttonDesc.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  buttonNo.parentElement.classList.add("active");
}
buttonNo.onclick = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < originalHours.length; i++) {
    times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = originalHours[i];
  }
  buttonNo.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  buttonAsc.parentElement.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.button-item {
  display: none;
}
.button-item.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-item active">
      <button id="Sort-item-asc">Sort Asc</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item-desc">Sort Desc</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-item">
      <button id="Sort-item-no">No Sort</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DRY - don’t repeat yourself

Comment: @niraj i wanna sort <div>s by hour , your code just sort hours and not relocating the <div>s